# WordPress URL rewriting; How to match URL parameters

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have URL: https://www.example.com/articles?page=2. I need to rewrite it to WordPress format: https://www.example.com/index.php?category_name=articles&paged=2.

I tried with rewrite rule like this:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^(.+?)\?page=([0-9]+)$', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top');
```

However this does not work. I have legacy CMS that I try to migrate to WP and I need to keep old URL structure.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to register your custom query variable using add_rewrite_tag. Add this to your theme's functions.php file or a custom plugin:

```
function custom_rewrite_tags() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%my_page%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tags');
```

second, define your custom rewrite rule using add_rewrite_rule in functions.php file

```
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^articles/([^/]+)/?$','index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&my_page=1','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
```

After making this changes, you need to flush the rewrite rules. You can do this by visiting the Settings > Permalinks page in your WordPress admin and clicking the Save button. This action refreshes the rewrite rules.

Comment: This doesn't even correspond to my question very well, not to mention that I tried similar solution with no success.